# FPO Data and system dlls

Tags: windows, debug-symbols

I have been playing around with the callstack and I noticed that sometimes I run into an FPO frame.
dbgHelp somehow can figure out where each frame ends and its symbols but I don't have the PDBS of DLLS such as kernel32 etc.

Do the system DLLs in windows contain FPO data? 
can I rely on it when using my program on a client's computer?
Do they contain any other debug information?

Comment: The .pdbs contain fpo data.  No, you cannot rely on them.  These Windows DLLs get updated constantly.

Comment: It doesn't matter if they get updated because I will anyway read the PFO data from the client's computer, I won't use hard-coded predetermined symbols or such.

Comment: I also read that FPO data can be put in the EXE or DLL itself. my question is if that is where they put it.

Comment: Hard to find something that isn't there.  The Windows standard is using the .pdb file.  Pretty obvious that it is, you would get a good stack trace in the debugger if it was stored in the dll.

Comment: wait, so you're saying that I use the ntDll.pdb without knowing it? I never downloaded it. does microsoft provide the PDBs built-in with windows???

Answer (score 2):

Public symbols for system DLLs are available if you set your symbols path to ://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols. IIRC many Windows components are compiled with FPO turned off. But what exactly are you trying to accomplish? What "debug" info are you looking for?

Comment: I'm looking mostly for debug symbols. I tried using "SymFromAddr" on NtDelayExecution which is in ntDll.dll but I don't have the PDB for it, so that's weird. I want to be able to stackwalk even FPO frame and for that i need the FPO information.